# Como especificar objeto no getcomponent?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Como faço pra especificar cada objeto no `getcomponent`?
Eu fiz este script, mas não sei especificar para cada `animator`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class anim2: MonoBehaviour 
{
    Animator optionsubir;
    Animator subirplay2;
    Animator extralado;
    public void ChamarAnimacao() 
    {
        optionsubir.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
        subirplay2.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
        extralado.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
    }
}
```

Comment: Colega, sua pergunta não está clara. O que vc quer dizer com "especificar"? O seu código está errado porque os atributos declarados (`optionsubir`, por exemplo) não foram *inicializados*, e como estão nulos (com `null`) isso vai gerar um erro na hora de tentar invocar `GetComponent`. Se o que você quer fazer é permitir a referência externa (via o *Inspector* do editor), a resposta que você tem está correta: basta adicionar o `public` na frente da declaração. Caso contrário, explique melhor a sua dificuldade, ok?

Comment: E, só pra constar, para separar os papéis (programador vs animador, por exemplo) é mais comum o animador construir toda a animação (que pode incluir até mais do que um clipe de animação!) e te fornecer um "gatilho" (um *trigger*) que você invoca diretamente no `Animator` com o método [`SetTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html).

Comment: Invocar `Play` diretamente numa animação funciona, mas não é uma boa prática porque vc perde a flexibilidade que esse recurso de [máquinas de estados de animação](https://github.com/enricllagostera/AprendendoUnity/wiki/Anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-m%C3%A1quinas-de-estados) te dá.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos supor que você tem 3 objetos e que precisa rodar as animações (a situação não ficou clara, se entendi errado por favor me corrija).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class anim2: MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Animator optionsubir; //Ao dizer que Animator é public, no
    public Animator subirplay2; //editor do Unity você pode arrastar o
    public Animator extralado; //gameObject que contem o Animator 
                              //desejado 
    public void ChamarAnimacao() 
    {
        optionsubir.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
        subirplay2.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
        extralado.GetComponent<Animation>().Play ("optionsubir");
    }
}
```

Também parece que você omitiu um parâmetro na chamada do método Play, dê uma olhada [na documentação do Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) para mais informações.

Comment: tipo, estou querendo puxar 3 animações que estão em diferentes objetos em apenas um butão

Comment: vi em uma página dizia  que pra poder puxar as demais tinha que  especificar cada gameobject, isso eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Pode fazer assim então: declara no começo do código 3 GameObjects públicos. Mantem teus animator do jeito que estão. Na função Start() faz assim: `optionsubir = nomeDoGameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();`.
Daí `optionsubir.animation.Play("nome da animação")` quando for dar play na animação.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a resposta do Raphael está certa, você só precisa tornar as variáveis públicas, assim, no inspector, você pode simplesmente arrastar as animações correspondentes. Acredito que é a maneira mais fácil e leve. Pode fazer por código também, mas vai ter que dizer no void Start quais são os animators, pois no seu código eles estão nulos, são só 3 variáveis que podem receber instâncias do tipo Animator, mas que não tem nada ainda, é como criar um int ou float, dar nome, mas não falar qual o valor, ele vai ser nulo. O que vc teria que fazer para dizer qual o "valor" dos seus Animators é algo do tipo:

```
Animator optionSubir;

void Start
{
    optionSubir = GameObject.Find("nome do objeto com a animação").getComponent<Animator>();
}
```